# How do I get the keccak256 in Solidity by a string type data rather than bytes

Tags: solidity

I want to take a ECC public key to get a address in Solidity, and the test address is
`0xa085fd8030c37DcBb40a5793e08cC3CC8D154E24`

My code snippet is below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;
contract PubToAddr {
    string public str = "0xdf5242e7ab9522520d7db462ea7837a67d726ae573039d42c7391f27f78807e9c569dedff8537bf212b8a167070906d94aa67ddec4def84a24c0d840341c750d"; 
    // a test public key
    
    function PubtoAddr(bytes memory str_) pure public returns(bytes20) {
        return( bytes20((uint160(uint256(keccak256(str_))))) );
    } 

    function PubtoAddr2() view public returns(bytes20) {
        bytes memory b = bytes(str);
        return( bytes20(uint160(uint256(keccak256(b)))) );
    }
    
}
```

then the result of executing both of those function is.

[image]

It'll get two different answers, the correct one is the answer of `PubtoAddr`.
I would like to ask why those answers are different.

And I need to make those public key convert to address automatically.

just like this code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;
contract PubToAddr {
    string[] public str; 
    address[] public addr;
    // str will contain {"pubkey1", "pubkey2"...};

    function PubtoAddr2() public returns(address[] memory) {
        uint i;
        for(i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
            bytes memory b = bytes(str[i]);
            addr.push(address(bytes20(uint160(uint256(keccak256(b))))));
        }
        return addr;
    }

}
```

This code will get the wrong answers obviously, because its structure is the same as PubtoAddr2,But I could't input those data from outside.
How should I fix my code.

Answer (score 0):

In the first function, the passed parameter is directly accepted as a bytes type and is processed as is. However, in the second function, the str string is converted to a bytes type, and its output becomes a hexadecimal representation of the ASCII values. To fix this, you can try:

```
    function PubtoAddr(string calldata str_) pure public returns(bytes20) {
        bytes memory b = bytes(str_);
        return( bytes20(uint160(uint256(keccak256(b)))) );
    }
```